# Best practice of API Gateway implementation if the backend has its own authentication

Tags: api, authentication, microservices, backend, api-gateway

I know one of API Gateway offers is to provide a security layer of any backend APIs. But how if the case is the backend has its own authentication already (let say api key, jwt or other)? What is the better approach / best practice:

1. Modify those backend APIs to become "plain API" (without any auth), so will rely only on API Gateway auth (OAuth2)
2. Keep the backend auth as it is, but then create a microservice that will act as wrapper API to handle that backend auth.

The goal is to prevent double authentication & give the same experience to the clients where they only need to pass 1 authentication which is by the API Gateway. Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what API gateway and authentication server do you use?

Comment: @KDW Hi, we're using Apigee X by Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep the backend's API security. There is nothing wrong with having secured communication behind an API gateway. As a matter of fact, I recall this being a recommended approach.

To prevent double authentication, would it be a suggestion to define a public (unsecured) end-point on the API gateway to access the authentication end-point of the authentication server used by your backend services. The client receives the authentication token from that authentication server and the API gateway passes the token through to the API of your backend services.

Another possibility could be to authenticate towards the API gateway but let the API gateway use the same authentication server as your backend services. Some gateways allow you to forward the authentication to an authentication server somewhere outside of the API gateway.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Really appreciate it. I will bring up these options in our discussion. One question, if the case requires us to use Authentication from the API gateway as generic auth for all APIs instead of backend auth, then the only option is to build another experience microservice to handle this backend authentication? We will use Apigee X gateway by the way.

Comment: Not necessarily. Can't your backend services point to the authentication endpoint of the API gateway instead of the authentication server currently used by those services? I would expect your microservices to use some kind of library to handle the authentication flow. It should not be that hard to point to a different authentication server then. Lets compare it (to give an example) with Spring Security in a Spring Boot application. Your application.properties can point to any authentication server supporting the Spring application's security mechanism (e.g. OAuth2).